# ¿Reducción de código utilizando herencia e interfaces?

Tags: java, poo, clase, estructuras-de-datos, herencia

Tengo una pregunta sobre siguiente ejercicio, en la NOTA dice que no se permiten elementos duplicados en las clases, y en la solución del ejercicio, en 3 clases (clases: AutoLujo,AutoCompacto y Vagon) puse el mismo código (mismos métodos y atributos) porque no halle otra posible solución para el ejercicio, hay manera de corregir el código repetido? o así ya esta bien la solución ?.

**Ejercicio:** Una agencia vendedora de autos desea un sistema computacional para administrar los datos de sus vehículos y clasificarlos por tipo. Todos los autos tienen los siguientes datos:

- Número de serie del motor
- Marca
- Año
- Precio

Los vehículos se clasifican en autos *compactos, autos de lujo, camionetas y vagonetas*. Para los autos y vagonetas, también es importante almacenar la cantidad de pasajeros; mientras que para las camionetas se debe controlar la capacidad de carga en kgs. y la cantidad de ejes y de rodadas.

Modelar este sistema e instancie cada una de las clases, asignándole datos mediante sus respectivas propiedades. Agregar un constructor con parámetros a cada clase para inicializar sus datos e invoque el constructor de la clase base desde el constructor de cada clase derivada (no utilice constructores default). 
Implemente la sobrescritura del método ToString() para mostrar los datos de cada tipo de auto. 
 
**NOTA:** No se permiten componentes duplicados en las clases ni clases vacías (sin elementos).

```
    interface Pasajeros
    { 
    int getCantidadPasajeros();
    void setCantidadPasajeros(int n); 
    }


    class Auto 
    { 
    private int numSerieMotor,año;
    private String marca;
    private double precio;

    Auto(){}
    Auto(int numSerieMotor, int año, String marca,double precio)
    {
        this.numSerieMotor=numSerieMotor;
        this.año=año;
        this.marca=marca;
        this.precio=precio;
    }

    public String toString() 
    { 
        return numSerieMotor+" "+ año+" "+marca+" "+ precio;
    }




    }

    class AutoCompacto extends Auto implements Pasajeros
    {   private int pasajeros;

    AutoCompacto(int numSerieMotor, int año, String marca,double precio)
    {
        super(numSerieMotor,año,marca,precio);
    }
    AutoCompacto(){}

    public String toString() 
    {   
      return super.toString()+" "+pasajeros;

    }
     public  int getCantidadPasajeros() 
    {
     return pasajeros;
    }
    public void setCantidadPasajeros(int n)
    {
    pasajeros=n;
    }


    }

    class AutoLujo extends Auto implements Pasajeros
    {   private int pasajeros;

     AutoLujo(int numSerieMotor, int año, String marca,double precio)
    {
        super(numSerieMotor,año,marca,precio);
    }

     public String toString() 
    {   
       return super.toString()+" "+pasajeros;

    }
     public  int getCantidadPasajeros() 
    {
     return pasajeros;
    }
    public void setCantidadPasajeros(int n)
    {
    pasajeros=n;
    }

    }

     class Camioneta extends Auto
    {  
    private int capacidadCarga;
    private int cantidadEjes;
    private int cantidadRodadas;

    Camioneta (int numSerieMotor, int año, String marca,double precio,int 
    capacidadCarga,int cantidadEjes,
    int cantidadRodadas)
    {
        super(numSerieMotor,año,marca,precio);
        this.capacidadCarga=capacidadCarga;
        this.cantidadEjes=cantidadEjes;
        this.cantidadRodadas=cantidadRodadas;
    }

    int getCarga()
    {
       return capacidadCarga; 
    }
     int getEjes()
    {
       return cantidadEjes; 
    }
      int getRodadas()
    {
       return cantidadRodadas; 
    }
      void setCarga(int n)
      {
          capacidadCarga=n;
      }
      void setEjes(int n)
      {
          cantidadEjes=n;
      }
      void setRodadas(int n)
      {
          cantidadRodadas=n;
      }

      public String toString() 
      {   

        return super.toString()+" "+capacidadCarga+" "+cantidadEjes+" 
      "+cantidadRodadas;
      }


      }

      class Vagon extends Auto implements Pasajeros
      {  private int pasajeros;

       Vagon(int numSerieMotor, int año, String marca,double precio)
      {
        super(numSerieMotor,año,marca,precio);
       }

      public String toString() 
      {   

        return super.toString()+" "+pasajeros;
      }

      public int getCantidadPasajeros(){
      return pasajeros;
       }
      public void setCantidadPasajeros(int n)
       {
     pasajeros=n;
      }
      }

     public class Tarea22ago 
      {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Auto x[]=new Auto[4];

       x[1]=new AutoCompacto();//analogo a AutoLujo();


       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Introduzca los datos del auto de lujo:"+"\n");
       System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de serie del motor");
       int a=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la marca");
       String b=s.next();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el año");
       int c=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el precio");
       double d=s.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de pasajeros");
       int e=s.nextInt();
       x[0]=new AutoLujo(a,c,b,d);
       ((AutoLujo)x[0]).setCantidadPasajeros(e);
       System.out.println(x[0].toString());//xq ponerle el s.o.p, si return 
       //ya regresa la cadena?

       System.out.println("Introduzca los datos del vagon:"+"\n");
       System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de serie del motor");
       int f=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la marca");
       String g=s.next();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el año");
       int h=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el precio");
       double i=s.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de pasajeros");
       int j=s.nextInt();
       x[2]=new Vagon(f,h,g,i);
       ((Vagon)x[2]).setCantidadPasajeros(j);
       System.out.println(x[2].toString());

       System.out.println("Introduzca los datos de la camioneta:"+"\n");
       System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de serie del motor");
       int k=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la marca");
       String l=s.next();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el año");
       int m=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca el precio");
       double n=s.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de carga");
       int o=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de ejes");
       int p=s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de rodadas");
       int q=s.nextInt();
       x[3]=new Camioneta(k,m,l,n,o,p,q);

       System.out.println(x[3].toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema es necesario implementar dos jerarquía de clases abstractas, en tu caso serian Vehículo y Auto, de las cuales Camioneta y Auto extienden o heredan de Vehículo, siendo la clase Auto la súper clase de AutoLujo, AutoCompacto y Vagoneta en la cual se implementa el atributo para definir la cantidad de pasajeros.
De esta forma no se contaminan las otras clases con atributos y métodos que no necesitan implementar.

**Codigo**

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {

    public int numSerieMotor;
    public int year;
    public String marca;
    public double precio;

    public Vehiculo(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio) {
        super();
        this.numSerieMotor = numSerieMotor;
        this.year = year;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

}

public abstract class Auto extends Vehiculo {

    public int pasajeros;

    public Auto(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio, int pasajeros) {
        super(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio);
        this.pasajeros = pasajeros;
    }

}

public class AutoLujo extends Auto {

    public AutoLujo(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio, int pasajeros) {
        super(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio, pasajeros);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AutoLujo [pasajeros=" + pasajeros + ", numSerieMotor=" + numSerieMotor + ", year=" + year
                + ", marca=" + marca + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
    }

}

public class AutoCompacto extends Auto {

    public AutoCompacto(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio, int pasajeros) {
        super(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio, pasajeros);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AutoCompacto [pasajeros=" + pasajeros + ", numSerieMotor=" + numSerieMotor + ", year=" + year
                + ", marca=" + marca + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
    }

}

public class Vagoneta extends Auto {

    public Vagoneta(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio, int pasajeros) {
        super(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio, pasajeros);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vagoneta [pasajeros=" + pasajeros + ", numSerieMotor=" + numSerieMotor + ", year=" + year
                + ", marca=" + marca + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
    }

}

public class Camioneta extends Vehiculo {

    public int capacidadCarga;
    public int cantidadEjes;
    public int cantidadRodadas;

    public Camioneta(int numSerieMotor, int year, String marca, double precio, int capacidadCarga, int cantidadEjes,
            int cantidadRodadas) {
        super(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio);
        this.capacidadCarga = capacidadCarga;
        this.cantidadEjes = cantidadEjes;
        this.cantidadRodadas = cantidadRodadas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Camioneta [capacidadCarga=" + capacidadCarga + ", cantidadEjes=" + cantidadEjes
                + ", cantidadRodadas=" + cantidadRodadas + ", numSerieMotor=" + numSerieMotor + ", year=" + year
                + ", marca=" + marca + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
    }

}
```

**Un ejemplo de como debes crear las instancias de las distintas clases**

```
public class Trabajo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehiculo vehiculos[] = new Vehiculo[4];

    int numSerieMotor = 0;
    int year = 0;
    int pasajeros = 0;
    int carga = 0;
    int ejes = 0;
    int rodadas = 0;
    double precio = 0;
    String marca = "";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca los datos del auto de lujo:" + "\n");
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de serie del motor");
    numSerieMotor = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la marca");
    marca = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el año");
    year = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el precio");
    precio = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de pasajeros");
    pasajeros = sc.nextInt();

    vehiculos[0] = new AutoCompacto(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio, pasajeros);
    System.out.println(vehiculos[0].toString());

    System.out.println("Introduzca los datos de la camioneta:" + "\n");
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de serie del motor");
    numSerieMotor = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la marca");
    marca = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el año");
    year = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el precio");
    precio = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de carga");
    carga = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de ejes");
    ejes = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de rodadas");
    rodadas = sc.nextInt();
    vehiculos[1] = new Camioneta(numSerieMotor, year, marca, precio, carga, ejes, rodadas);
    System.out.println(vehiculos[1].toString());

  }

}
```

Comment: hmm pero en la aplicación de la herencia, dices que `Vagoneta extends Auto` osea que una Vagoneta es un Auto? Mas bien, yo diria que una Vagoneta solo es un vehiculo pero no un auto

Comment: aah espera jaja..yo tambien lo puse asi

Comment: va depender del contexto en que se formule la descripción de la vagoneta por que puede referenciar a  una vagoneta de carga de  mercancías o de pasajeros.

Comment: y obviamente sus características serian diferente y no están formuladas en tu ejercicio.

Comment: Si tienes razón, otra cosa, porque denotaste con `abstract` a la clase `Vehiculo` y `Auto` ?

Comment: Se declaran abstractas para definir las subclases, ya que de estas no se pueden crear instancias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64370/discussion-between-david-navarro-astudillo-and-michelle).